# Create patch for series of existing changesets that were created without using MQ?

Tags: mercurial, patch, mq, mercurial-queue

I've recently started to work on an open source project which uses Mercurial.
I'm a new user to Mercurial, so I read the HG book and started working.
My goal was to write code and always pull and merge changes from the upstream 
so I can stay up-to-date. The area that I am working on is also under heavy
development by others so I do want to merge my changes after a long period of
time. I cloned a repo. So, my workflow is like this:

1. I created a bookmark mybook
2. `hg up mybook`
3. Write code

3.1 `hg commit -m 'new functions'`

4. `hg up default`
5. `hg pull`
6. `hg update`
7. `hg up mybook`
8. `hg merge default`
9. Go to step 3.

In my mind this is the simplest workflow that allows me to stay up-to-date. I
also have only one HEAD because I always merge.

Since I am not a contributor yet, I am not allowed to push changes to remote
repo.

Recently I wanted to show my work to a project lead and he said send me a patch.
And this is where I am stuck. `hg out` shows 10 changesets. First of which
appeard already a month ago. They're numbers are `3341, 3342, 3345, 3346, 3349, 3356, 3360, 3365, 3366, 3368`. The changeset numer `3368` is the tip.

I've recently read the chapter about the MQ extension. And this extensions seems to be what I need. But the problem is that I wrote code without using the MQ
extension.

So, how can I make use of the MQ extension on already created changesets so that
I can make a patch to send to the project lead so that he can apply it and see
my changes?

I've just issued `hg qinit`. What's next?
Issueing `hg qimport -r 3341` gives

```
abort: revision 3341 has unmanaged children
```

Reading the book and googling further does not help me. I need an advice.

PS I've tried not using hg and MQ at all: simple `diff -urN old/ new/` but I
want understand how to do it with the MQ.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use MQ for this task. Export changesets as set of patches with `hg export -r REVSET`

Comment: And, BTW, you can have less number of frictions in your workflow in 4-6 area

Comment: I think @LazyBadger means that you can `pull` and `merge` from `default` without updating away from your branch (if you don't mind doing so without reviewing the new version).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, don't use MQ. It's a parallel system, meant for keeping things out of the history, and more important you don't need it.

You were asked for "a patch", not a complete history of your work, so I would recommend sending it in the form of a single before-after diff. `hg export` will give you a series of diffs, for all the work you've done, including the merges.  I find it's far easier to read and review a single diff (before applying it). But instead of plain `diff`, use `hg diff` which knows to only look at tracked files, and has a number of other nice features (including the `--git` option, which provides richer metadata). This should do it:

```
hg up mybook
hg diff --git -r default > mywork.patch
```

Before sending it off, do an `hg up default` and apply the patch to check that it works without conflicts. And mention to the recipient which version of `default` you are patching against.

**Edit:** As you can read in the comments, @LazyBadger is a fan of the step-by-step patch generated by `export`. I prefer the single-step patch 
since my history is usually TMI: Nobody cares about all the times I added a forgotten file, or noticed a bug too late and fixed in in the next commit, etc.
Take your pick.

Comment: Don't mix `hg export` and `hg archive`, dude - export save **patch-file**

Comment: Sorry if that sounded misleading. `hg export` will generate a patch, containing separate diffs for each file _and for each changeset_ in the included range of revisions. So it includes multiple diffs for each file affected. `hg diff` will just compare the beginning and final state, and produce a  single spanning patch.

Comment: My interest is not in whether the output of `export` can properly be called a patch, but in whether it's useful to a project lead wanting to review a potential contribution.

Comment: Well, you are right in mentioning differences, but anyway - lead *will not* verify patch by eye (sure) - it will be applied to some (mercurial) sandbox and export's diffs are somehow **healthier** in *this* case

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to make it clear that opinions differ on this.